# why osmdroid.jar file implentation in android studio throws error?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, osmdroid, offlineapps

I am trying to use `Osmdroid` [link](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid)for offline map in android studio and when i try to use it in the `xml` it throws the error, as i am using this the first time i couldn't figure out where i have done wrong please let me Error:Content is not allowed in prolog.

```
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
/Users/Avi/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/res/Library/osmdroid_android.jar
Error:Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.> /Users/Avi/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/src/main/res/Library/osmdroid_android.jar:0:0: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.know how to solve this
```

> **SOLVED**
>   Thanks to Morrison Chang , if you are using android studio like me just put the dependecies no need to import the `.jar` file

```
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.2'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
```

Comment: How are you adding it to your project. If you are using AndroidStudio/Gradle - have you seen: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-add-the-osmdroid-library-via-Gradle

Comment: i am adding it just like it's been mentioned in the wiki i.e paste the `.jar` file in the project `add as library` and give permission in the manifest as well as add `compile persion ` in the build.gradle file

Answer (score 2):

As @MorrisonChang said, you need to add gradle dependencies as provided in [How to add the osmdroid library via Gradle](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-add-the-osmdroid-library-via-Gradle), which says:

> If you use Gradle you have to add the following dependency to your
>   build.gradle file:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.2'
>     compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
> }
> ```

Comment: @Virus if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.